# Getting "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Kerberos validation not succesful" exception

Tags: authentication, kerberos, jaas

We are using Jaas.conf, BEST properties and spn to generate kerberos token and in the same application we are using spring security spn go filter to validate the token with keytab and system account.
Our application is acting as server and client both(server to validate REST request and client to generate token and hit REST endpoint)

Can anybody help in this scenario?

Thanks in advance !!!